# How to find all the elements containing a certain text using xpath Selenium and Python

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait, xpath-1.0

I tried

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text()),'panel')]")
```

but it's only pulling through a singular result when there should be about 25.

I want to find all the xpath id's containing the word panel on a webpage in selenium and create a list of them. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you show us the example of html with the objects you need to look up?

Answer (score 1):

The xpath in your question has an error, not sure if it is a typo but this will not fetch any results.
There is an extra parantheses.

Instead of :

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text()),'panel')]")
```

It should be :

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'panel')]")
```

**Tip**: To test your locators(xpath/CSS) - instead of directly using it in code, try it out on a browser first.
Example for Chrome:

1. Right click on the web page you are trying to automate
2. Click Inspect and do a CTRL-F.
3. Type in your xpath and press ENTER

You should be able to scroll through all the matched elements and also verify the total match count

Answer (score 0):

To collect all the elements containing a certain text e.g. *panel* using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *XPATH* and `contains()`:

  ```
  elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(., 'panel')]")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```